# Cocos2d animation delay after some time(minutes)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem in cocos2d animation, While running the animation for the first time,which works perfectly,after some time, the animation speed goes slow

I have used the below code

```
-(void)animateImages:(NSString *)animationName startImageName:(NSString*)sImage  individualImageName:(NSString *)imgName withDelay:(CGFloat)delay startFrame:(NSInteger)sFrame endFrame:(NSInteger)eFrame {

isAnimating=YES;


[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",animationName]];        

// Create a sprite sheet with the March images
CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",animationName]];



[self addChild:spriteSheet z:0];

// Load up the frames of our animation
NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = sFrame; i <= eFrame; i=i+2) {
    [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d.jpg",imgName,i]]];//@"stand march %d.jpg"
}


NSLog(@"After NSMutableArray");


    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:delay];
//    CCAction *standByAtion =[CCSequence actions:                          
//                             [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES] times:1],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callAgain:)],nil];

CCAction *standByAtion =[CCSequence actions:                          
                         [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO] times:1],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setAnimatingToFalseAfterAnimation:)],nil];


 [walkAnimFrames removeAllObjects];
 walkAnimFrames=nil;

CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCSprite *images = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sImage]];//@"stand march 101.jpg"

images.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
images.scaleX=1.6;
images.scaleY=1.59;




[spriteSheet addChild:images];

[images runAction:standByAtion];

if (!isInInitMethod && isTalking==NO) {
    NSString *audioName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Jump.caf"];
    [self playSoundEffectNamed:audioName];
}
}
```

Comment: observe the fps, if it is dropping, then you're doing something wrong. Perhaps allocating again and again.

Comment: Are you calling that method again and again? If so, you are allocating all those objects and loading all the animation frames far too many times. You should do that ONCE in your init (for example) and then just set the animation to use when you need to animate.

Answer (score 0):

If the runloop isn't running a full cycle, then autoreleased objects aren't getting deallocated. Use Instruments and track your allocations.